# Windows Tablet data and power from one USB

Tags: usb, battery, hub, splitter

My Windows tablet has one mini USB port which is used for charging the tablet's battery as well as for data transfer but because there is only the one USB port it won't let me do both at the same time.   I am wondering if there is a splitter or hub which will allow me to plug into the tablet's mini USB port and have two USB A ends,  one of which can be used for data transfer and the other can be plugged into a 110v charger (5v) allowing me to keep the tablet charged while data is being transmitted on the first one.

My application requires hours of continuous data transfer and I want to be able to keep the tablet charged up while in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows tablet otg simultaneously charge?](https://superuser.com/questions/1124237/windows-tablet-otg-simultaneously-charge)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tablet devices gets power from the same usb port at the same time while data transfer take place. You don't need a splitter, the laptop or desktop also serve as the power source for the tablet device. If this is not the case with your tablet, then I think it is an exceptional case. Re check the battery charging status while connected with PC and see your tablet's documentation.